# IE11/Win7 input (with specific content) event is triggered on page reload , input field is a react component which triggers onInputChange event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cross-browser, internet-explorer-11, frontend

On IE11 , i have this issue where , with specific content in the input field , input event is triggered on page reload, which makes the dropdown menu to appear without any action from the user. 
The specific content being characters such as ü,ö or ä.Basically the input feild is react based component.
This happens only on IE11.Please have look at the screenshot.

Before reload ,
[image]

After reload the dropdown menu appears, which should happen only when onInputChange is triggered:
[image]

required behaviour would be : No input event triggered on page reload.

Comment: Place the event handler outside of the onload event handler in a script block at the bottom the <body>. Use a global variable (not declared in the onload event handler)... Include reproducible mashups with your questions.

Comment: the input field is react component. so there is onChange event on the component itself, because it should show suggestions based on userinput.